# django.core.urlresolvers.resolve incorrect behavior under apache non-root deployment

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

When a django app is deployed under a non-root apache url (with **WsgiScriptAlias /suburl /path_to_django.wsgi**) the **{%url%}** tag and the **django.core.urlresolvers.reverse** function take into account the **SCRIPT_NAME** variable and return urls of the form **/suburl/path_to_my_view**

However, when I use the **django.core.urlresolvers.resolve** function to resolve those urls it throws an error. That forces me to strip the **SCRIPT_NAME** of the generated urls before calling resolve. Is this the expected behavior or am I misunderstanding everything?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same kind of problem:

- SCRIPT_NAME defined in my apache config
- a call to `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` outside the `wsgi` didnt prepend the prefix
- in any view or resource, a call to the same method prepended the prefix

I managed to have the prefix automatically prepended using the next lines of code:

```
# in settings.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import set_script_prefix
...
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = "your-prefix"
set_script_prefix(FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME)
...
```

The first line makes sure your wsgi uses your prefix every time. The second one sets the prefix, so that `reverse` will find it.

Please note that you need to have the same prefix in your apache conf. It's a bit redundant, but the cleaner fix I found.